# Bash Case statement: check whether string ends in number

Tags: bash, scripting, numbers, case

Inside a case statement, I want to check whether or not the "--sn" command is followed by a number (1-254).
I thought i'd just use --sn*, but apperently * doesn't work for numbers?

```
case "$1" in
    --sn*    ) var=$(echo $1 | cut -dn -f2 )
             ;;
    *        ) break ;;
esac
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: That should work. What is the value of `$1` exactly? What do you see if you add `set -x` to the top of the script?

Comment: A simpler way to set `var` is with `var=${1#--sn}`.

Comment: the set -x did the trick I was able to figure out what was going wrong, thank you.

Prior to the the --sn* statement I had already written a * [0-9] * case statement, and it let throught anything with a number in it (I thought it would solely let strings of strict numeric characters pass...) Moved it to the bottom and now it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
  --sn*[0-9]) echo "$1 ends with a number"
              ;;
  *)          echo "$1 does not end with a number"
              ;;
esac
```